# How to execute function only after value is loaded?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using firebase to execute code as soon as page is loaded with useEffect. 
I have a state of user in Redux and it takes few seconds to go from null to actual user info. 
My problem is that code fires instantly and im not sure how to make it wait till user info is loaded.

In the code error is shown due to "null" value of "user.email"

```
const {user} = useSelector(state=>state.user)
const [myGames, setMyGames] = useState([])

useEffect(()=> {
    const unsubscribe = db.collection("games")
    .where("username", "==", user.email)
    .onSnapshot(snapshot=> setMyGames(snapshot.docs.map(doc=> doc.data().game_title)))

    return ()=> {
        unsubscribe()
    }    
}, [])
```

Answer (score 3):

When you are giving [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) an empty array as a second argument, you are telling it to run once on after the first component render. This does not wait for the state change. In order to bind the useEffect to a data point, bind it by passing it in the array given.

Note: This will trigger the effect every time user is updated!

Example:

```
const {user} = useSelector(state=>state.user)
const [myGames, setMyGames] = useState([])

    useEffect(()=> {
        if(user.email !== null){
        const unsubscribe = db.collection("games")
        .where("username", "==", user.email)
        .onSnapshot(snapshot=> setMyGames(snapshot.docs.map(doc=> 
           doc.data().game_title)))
        }
        return ()=> {
            unsubscribe()
        }    
    }, [user])
```

Comment: Thanks @aviya.developer for adding description on my solution ..I'm new here, forgot about giving explaination of solution